# How to find an exact different numbers from string using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

I need to find a number from a string value like:

```
tag:example.com,1999:blog-124938250235712450.post-092348192357990021
```

I have used this method via JQuery:

JavaScript & HTML Code:

```js
var getId  = 'tag:example.com,1999:blog-124938250235712450.post-092348192357990021',
    postID = getId.match(/post-\w*/),
    blogID = getId.match(/blog-\w*/);

/* Print Post ID */
$('#post-id').html(postID);

/* Print Blog ID */
$('#blog-id').html(blogID);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Getting Post ID : <span id='post-id'></span>
<br/>
Getting Blog ID : <span id='blog-id'></span>
```

So, the output for: 
**POST ID** is like `post-092348192357990021` 
**BLOG ID** is like `blog-124938250235712450`.

But, I just need the digits for each one for example: 
**POST ID** like this: `092348192357990021` 
**BLOG ID** like this: `124938250235712450`.

I hope you help me guys 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `postID = getId.match(/post-\w*/).split('-').pop()`

Comment: @connexo You can't split the result of an match. Just `.split('-').pop()` would do it.

Comment: A bit unrelated to the question at hand but if this snippet is present within Blogger's template code, then for the Blog ID, you can also get it via the following data tag - `<data:blog.blogId/>`

Comment: @PrayagVerma Yep, but my code need CDATA and to add blog ID as a variable inside a CDATA using blogger tag, so, will don't work properly! maybe if I create a global scope variable will work, I will try this idea because it sounds good! Thanks!

Comment: You can exclude the BlogID data tag from CDATA section by introducing multiple CDATA sections within that `<script>` tag so that the Blogger data tag can be executed because of it being excluded from every CDATA section. For example, check `<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
   var blogID = <data:blog.blogId/>;
/*]]>*/

var bloggerID = <data:blog.blogId/>;

/*<![CDATA[*/
   var bID = <data:blog.blogId/>;
/*]]>*/
</script>`

In this snippet, `bloggerID` variable will be able to stored the BlogID value whereas other variables won't have BlogID value because data tags were not executed there

Comment: Yep, of course, that's what I have tried a few seconds and is working so nice! thank you, Verma :) are you a blogger developer too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RegEx capture groups `()` and select the capture via it's index `[1]`.

If you only need numbers you could also just capture the numbers with `\d`.

```js
var getId  = 'tag:example.com,1999:blog-124938250235712450.post-092348192357990021',
    postID = getId.match(/post-(\d*)/),
    blogID = getId.match(/blog-(\d*)/);

/* Print Post ID */
$('#post-id').html(postID[1]);

/* Print Blog ID */
$('#blog-id').html(blogID[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Getting Post ID : <span id='post-id'></span>
<br/>
Getting Blog ID : <span id='blog-id'></span>
```

Comment: i will never get familiar with those regEx - i always have to google it xD good solution

Comment: @Infinyteam: If you're going to use regex, you certainly don't need two of them. `var ids = getId.match(/^.*?blog-(\d+)\.post-(\d+)$/);`

Answer (score 1):

If that's the exact format, you don't even need a regex.

```js
var getId  = 'tag:example.com,1999:blog-124938250235712450.post-092348192357990021';
var [postID, blogID] = getId.split(":blog-")[1].split(".post-");

/* Print Post ID */
$('#post-id').html(postID);

/* Print Blog ID */
$('#blog-id').html(blogID);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Getting Post ID : <span id='post-id'></span>
<br/>
Getting Blog ID : <span id='blog-id'></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use split and pop after you've converted your object to a String:

```js
var getId  = 'tag:example.com,1999:blog-124938250235712450.post-092348192357990021',
    postID = getId.match(/post-\w*/).toString().split('-').pop(),
    blogID = getId.match(/blog-\w*/).toString().split('-').pop();


/* Print Post ID */
$('#post-id').html(postID);

/* Print Blog ID */
$('#blog-id').html(blogID);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Getting Post ID : <span id='post-id'></span>
<br/>
Getting Blog ID : <span id='blog-id'></span>
```

Comment: Why did you make your solution even more horrible? There was no need for `match` and even less need for `toString`.  :-o

Comment: My intention was to make OP's code work with as little as possible additions. Adding `.toString().split('-').pop()` and otherwise modifying nothing seemed the smallest solution staying closest to what OP already had.

Comment: Why would one want to avoid deletion (of `match()`) and force such a solution? You had half of a good solution from the start with `.split()` so adding more code didn't improve the solution.

Comment: If you start with a regex may as well use it fully. I would support either all regex, or all chained methods but not a combination.